# namespace in static functions

Tags: c++, static, namespaces

I want to write a little Singleton class that looks like:

```
#include <vector>

class Interpreter {

private:
    static Interpreter* interInstance;
    Interpreter() {}

public:
    static Interpreter* getInstance();
    ~Interpreter() {}

};

Interpreter* Interpreter::interInstance = 0;

Interpreter* Interpreter::getInstance(){
if (!interInstance)
    interInstance = new Interpreter();

return interInstance;
}
```

But this will produce this exception:

```
multiple definition of `Interpreter::getInstance()
```

This error can be corrected by wrapping the class and the function in one namespace.
But I don't really understand why I need a namespace.
There is one declaration of getInstance() and one implementation, no?

Comment: If you are including this code from several translation units, then there are several implementations of `getInstance()` and `interInstance`

Comment: Adding on, you should always wrap your headers in a header guard.

Comment: Are you using an anonymous namespace, i.e. `namespace { /* stuff */ }`?

Comment: yes, over the whole file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the definition outside the header, in an implementation file, for both the member initialization and the method:

**Interpreter.h**

```
class Interpreter {

private:
    static Interpreter* interInstance;
    Interpreter() {}

public:
    static Interpreter* getInstance();
    ~Interpreter() {}

};
```

**Interpreter.cpp**

```
#include "Interpreter.h"
Interpreter* Interpreter::interInstance = 0;

Interpreter* Interpreter::getInstance(){
if (!interInstance)
    interInstance = new Interpreter();

return interInstance;
}
```

Inside a class or struct definition, `static` doesn't give symbols internal linkage as it does outside, so you're breaking the **one definition rule**.

If multiple translation units include a header that contains non-inline methods or define the same symbol, you'll run into multiple definition.

Comment: It might be worth adding a pointer to some larger description of the many inconsistent meanings of "static" in C++, but I think that one-line explanation is as good as anyone's ever going to do in one sentence.